# How get Android 2.1 SDK to recognize new class: SignalStrength

Tags: android, signal-strength

The new Android 2.1 SDK (version 7) has a new class called SignalStrength: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html

I updated my SDK in Eclipse to include the 2.1 add-on, and now I am trying to use this new class.  However, when I go to do an import android.telephony.SignalStrength, it can't find it.  Do I have to somehow reset my project to refresh the SDK so it knows about the new libraries?  How can I get it to recognize this new class?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make sure the API level of your project is set to 7.

Comment: Figured it out. For some reason the default.properties file got messed up and was keeping my project set to SDK 4. I changed it to 7, and things shaped up.